# Equivalent of mysql_insert_id() for Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_insert_id alternative for postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956/mysql-insert-id-alternative-for-postgresql)

Is there a Postgresql equivalent of mysql_insert_id() to get the ID generated in the last query ??

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer then the simplest way is to use `RETURNING`:

```
$result = pg_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (123) RETURNING foo_id");
$insert_row = pg_fetch_row($result);
$insert_id = $insert_row[0];
```

For other alternatives see [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956/mysql-insert-id-alternative-for-postgresql).