# Fetching one single row from database using Perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

I am trying to run a simple database connection with Perl using postgreSQL

```
use DBI;

$database = "postgres";
$user     = "postgres";
$password = "admin";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(  "dbi:Pg:dbname=$database"
                       , $user
                       , $password
                      )
or die "Can't Connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

# get data from the URL string
my $firstname = "haroon";
my $lastname ="ash";
my $age = 24;

# insert the data into the database
my $query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname, age) 
             VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname', '$age')";
$dbh->do($query);

# get the ID of the inserted person
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM people";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
my $rv =$sth->execute;
if($rv < 0){
   print $DBI::errstr;
}
else {
   my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref; 
   my $person_id = $row->{'max'};
   print $firstname, $lastname 
       . "was successfully inserted at position " 
       . $person_id;
}
```

I am trying to print the person id which  i had entered latest. But `my $person_id = $row->{'max'}` seems to give me the correct answer instead of `my $person_id = $row->{'id'};`. I am not understanding why is that.

Comment: Take a look at [`mysql_insert_id alternative for postgresql`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/55956/1733163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to set column alias for query,

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM people";
```

as postgres is putting his own alias for you, and that is `max`.

If all you want is last inserted id, you can

```
my $query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname, age) 
         VALUES (?,?,?)
         returning id
";
```

and fetch query as you would do with `select`. (check [pg docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html))

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot note that this is merely a cp from OP, but here you go, updated.

Comment: You should at least tell them that what they're doing is a bad idea and why they should use placeholders instead. I could do that in a comment but since you've already given an answer showing a query, you might as well slap a little education on the OP.

Comment: I didn't downvote, it must have been Borodin ;) But seriously, I'd be happy to remove it if you add some *explanation* about placeholders. Nothing wrong with mentioning strict and warnings as well.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot perhaps some other time, feel free to write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RETURNING` keyword to return the `id` associated with the row you just inserted:

```
my $query = '
  INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname, age)
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
  RETURNING id';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($firstname, $lastname, $age);
my $rv = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
printf "%s, %s was successfully inserted at position %d\n",
  $firstname, $lastname, $rv->{id};
```

Comment: Hey, what is this type of string (`$query`) called that works like a function? Can you provide some resources to learn more about it?

Comment: That type of string contains [query placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#Placeholders) so you don't have to worry about escaping the contents of `$lastname` properly, since (for example) `O'Malley` can contain single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not enter a PERSON_ID in your insert statement.

Instead it seems the ID field was populated by the DB, an auto increment value during insert, it seems.

Without knowing the table definition (and potential insert trigger on the table) it is hard/impossible to give you a better answer.